# KDE Neon ( 18.04 based ) stuck on emergency mode

Tags: kde-neon

**Relevant prequel** :

​

- 2 X SSD ( one 840 evo + one 850 evo )
- 2 X HDD

​

HDDs are used for storage, formatted on ext4. One of them used to have a 1Tb NTFS partition for Windows that has been deleted/ ext4 reformatted.

​

850 evo is entirely used for linux ( 18.04 based KDE Neon ) . 840 evo is used for Windows 10 ... usually dual-booting with another linux distro ( used to be Manjaro until ... recently ) .

​

Important: 840 evo SSD ( the one dual-booting Windows10+linux ) is always physically unplugged... until is going to be used ( not exactly often ) ; each time i plug the 840 SSD i unplug the 850 SSD .

​

**What happened**:

​

My Windows10 was acting funny last time i plugged the 840 SSD plus i wasn't feeling Manjaro... so i decided to re-install Windows 10, then make a dual boot with OpenSUSE Tumbleweed .

​

Unplugged my 850 SSD ( the one with 18.04 KDE Neon only ) , plugged the 840 SSD, booted from a live linux distro with Gparted and deleted everything on the 840 SSD & then... after a long while ( no issues, it just took too much time ) had Win10 installed... it was later than expected so just used the regular "shutdown" button from windows , unplugged the 840 SSD, plugged the 850 SSD and called it a day.

​

Next day, powered the computer ( with only my 850 SSD + 2 HDDs plugged ) ... and now Neon seems to be stuck in emergency mode O__O .

​

It shows something like this:

​

You are in emergency mode.

After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs,

"systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default"

or ^D to try again to boot into default mode".

​

​

every time i try to ctrl+d + exit or systemctl default it loads what it looks like some text loading sequence for Neon 14.4 and displays the same text as above.

From what i've found so far, it looks like my fstab could be wrong.

​

At this very moment i've unplugged everything but by 850 SSD and did "sudo nano /etc/fstab" but all i see is the UUID for dev sdb1 + swap file .

​
**What i've tried so far**

**First:** Plugged the 2 HDDs as well, started the SSD with 18.04 Neon, ejecuted "journalctl -xb" .... there's 1423 lines... i'm assuming i should check for the red lines ( ? ) .... and i spotted these two ( i think it's line 1011 and 1012 ) :

​

```
systemd-udevd [417] : Error calling EVIOCSKEYCODE on device node '/dev/input/event3' (scan code 0xc022d, key code 103) : Invalid argument

systemd-udevd [417] : Error calling EVIOCSKEYCODE on device node '/dev/input/event3' (scan code 0xc022e, key code 108) : Invalid argument
```

​

And then, on line - i think - 1092 there's another red line that reads:

​

```
systemd [1] : Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-1D5F3A4B09CF588F .device.
```

​

and just under that line ( not red colored ):

```
-- Subject: Unit dev-disk-by\x2duuid-1D5F3A4B09CF588F .device
```

​I'm assuming these last 2 lines are directly related to the first 2 .

**Second:**

tried running fsck from emergency mode but doesn't allow me to do so because /dev/sda1 is mounted.

Booted again from a live -buntu distro and followed these steps i've found:

​

> Run in the
>   terminal — wgethttp://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/e2fsprogs/e2fsprogs/v1.43.1/e2fsprogs-1.43.1.tar.gz
>
> ```
> Run in the terminal — tar xzf e2fsprogs-1.43.1.tar.gz
>
> Run in the terminal — cd e2fsprogs-1.43.1
>
> Run in the terminal — ./configure
>
> Run in the terminal- make
>
> Run in the terminal- cd e2fsck/
>
> Run in the terminal- sudo ./e2fsck -y <corrupt filesystem name>
> ```

​

applying that to /dev/sda1 . Rebooted... but it's still stuck showing the same red lines i posted above .

​

I'm doing all this with just one SSD plugged, the one with 18.04 Neon 5.14.4 installed

**Third:** Booted from a Kubuntu 18.10 live media, opened Konsole and then - as root - did "fsck /dev/sda1" ...  it say it's "clean" .

Rebooted the system, removed the live media, booted from the SSD with Neon... but it is still stuck on emergency mode.
​
What should i check/try next ?

Answer (score 1):

I kept searching for similar problems and plenty evidence pointed to the fstab file ... so I checked what was on mine, and it was this:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>

#Entry for /dev/sdb1 :
UUID=75d5863b-7463-475f-b3c1-259235486ee2   /   ext4    errors=remount-ro   0   1
#Entry for /dev/sda2 :
UUID=1D5F3A4B09CF588F   /media/myusername/1D5F3A4B09CF588F  ntfs-3g defaults,nodev,nosuid,locale=en_US.UTF-8    0   0
/swapfile   none    swap    sw  0   0
```

/dev/sda2 seemed to be my dvd-rom drive, which to be completely honest, I can't understand why it would be the one behind all this, bu I commented out that line so my fstab now looks like this:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>

#Entry for /dev/sdb1 :
UUID=75d5863b-7463-475f-b3c1-259235486ee2   /   ext4    errors=remount-ro   0   1
#Entry for /dev/sda2 :
#UUID=1D5F3A4B09CF588F  /media/ashberian/1D5F3A4B09CF588F   ntfs-3g defaults,nodev,nosuid,locale=en_US.UTF-8    0   0
/swapfile   none    swap    sw  0   0
```

... and it worked !!! Finally, Neon booted normally! I did lose my DVD drive it seems :|